# get_the_ID() in the footer returns wrong value

Tags: php, wp-query, loop, id, get-the-id

I'm using `get_the_ID()` in `footer.php` but it returns a wrong value.

It might come from any of the plugin which is altering The Loop without resetting it after with `wp_reset_postdata()` as mentioned in [$post->ID and the_id() always return the wrong value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39579/post-id-and-the-id-always-return-the-wrong-value).

Indeed the page shows a list of recent posts, etc. so this might modify the current Loop.

If I can't modify this (because of third party code), how to **get the ID of the current post** in the footer anyway, with PHP?

Comment: What happens if you call `wp_reset_postdata()` in your footer before the `get_the_ID()`?

Comment: Yes it works @kero but I wanted to know if there is another less intrusive method (than resetting the postdata).

Comment: Why would it be intrusive? `get_the_ID()` _should_ return the correct ID. Now most likely some third party code is not behaving nicely, and with calling `wp_reset_postdata()` you simply reset the state to how it should have been. If something breaks, get rid of that what broke (and whatever forgot to reset the postdata).

Comment: Thanks @kero, I think you can post as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an environment without third party code, `get_the_ID()` should give you the correct value. It sounds like some plugin is interfering with this.

So you can do what they forgot and simply call

```
wp_reset_postdata()
```

in your footer before you need the values.